# How to start a BaseX Unit Test Module in a XQuery script?

Tags: unit-testing, xquery, basex

I have pairs of XML databases that i want to iterate through and use it as input for unit tests. I'm using [BaseX Unit Testing Module](https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Unit_Module#Query). To give an example `validate.xqm` looks like this:

```
module namespace test="mytests";
 
declare variable $test:fibexDB external;
declare variable $test:autosarDB external;
 
declare variable $test:fibex := db:open($test:fibexDB);
declare variable $test:autosar := db:open($test:autosarDB);
 
declare %unit:test function test:validateCountSignals() {
  let $countSignalsFBX := count($test:fibex//*:SIGNAL)
  let $countSignalsASR := count($test:autosar//*:SYSTEM-SIGNAL)
  return unit:assert-equals($countSignalsFBX,$countSignalsASR + 5,concat('Database:',$test:fibexDB))
};
 
declare %unit:test function test:validateOEMExtension() {
  let $countOEMExtensionsFBX := count($test:fibex//*:OEM-SPECIFIC-EXTENSIONS)
  return unit:assert-equals($countOEMExtensionsFBX,1,concat('Database:',$test:fibexDB))
};
```

I know that the tests can be started with the TEST command or on the command line like this:

```
\bin\basex -oC:\UnitTestConverter\FlexRayTestResult.xml -b{mytests}fibexDB=DB01A -b{convertertests}autosarDB=DB01B -t validate.xqm
```

Is it also possible to start `validate.xqm` in a XQuery script? Or is there any other X-technology solution that let iterate through a set of input values and start one or more unit test modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found support for this question on [BaseX-Talk](https://mailman.uni-konstanz.de/mailman/listinfo/basex-talk). Hence i undeleted the question in order to give the answer here: "It is not possible.". But you can use `proc:system` and start a BaseX process for processing each test suite. I'm now using a function like this:

```
declare function test:runtest($database, $testmodule, $moduleid) {
  let $name := $database/@name
  let $args := ('-cp',$test:basexjar,'org.basex.BaseX','-b',concat('{unittest}testsuitesfile=',$test:testsuitesfile),'-b',concat('{unittest}configfile=',$test:configfile),'-b',concat('{unittest}tssid=',$test:tssid),'-b',concat('{unittest}dataid=',$database/@name),'-o',concat($test:unittestresultpath,$test:tssid,'_',$name,'_',$moduleid,'.xml'),'-t',$testmodule)
  return (
    try {proc:system('java',$args)} catch * { }
  )
};
```